# Expression that bounds Big O

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
    T(n) =  (n!n+n^3)(n^2+7logn)
```

How to find the expression (constant) that bounds n!n^3 ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not at all clear to me what you are asking. There are (infinitely) many expressions (functions) that bound the expression (function) `n!n^3`. That is a trivial statement. But none of them is constant in `n`.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking for an upper bound not involving factorial (!)? Perhaps involving just polynomial and exponential and logarithmic functions?

Comment: T(n) <= c(gn)

We have g(n) = O(n!n^3). How to find c in my case ?

Comment: since  T(n)  <=   n!n^3 + n!n^3 + n!n^3 + n!n^3. Hence O(n!n^3)  and constant will be 4,  correct ?

Comment: @SimonLeung That is correct. Didn't you ask this same question already and get this answer there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n! is O(n^n) so if

```
T(n) = (n!n+n^3)(n^2+7logn)
```

then T(n) is O(n^(n+3))